# how can i remove black screen at the end of video?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I want to remove black screen at the end of video in react Native video , there is no props in docs for that , any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using react-native-video, one solution is to `seek(0)` in your onEnd callback. You'll need to use the player ref.